# hoverable donut chart does not lose highlights when mouse leaves chart

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm having the following issue that can be reproduced even on Flot main example page,

And I was wondering if there's any way to overcome it.

Problem Description: Ssetting up the donut chart and using the `grid: { hoverable: true  }`  on it.

Next thing is placing the chart inside some div so that the upper and the lower bounder of the donut chart almost touching the div borders , Now... when i hover the donut slices they are being highlighted, BUT... if I "slide" the mouse FAST away from the chart the highlighted slice does not losses its highlighted... (which looks bad)

It can be reproduced in here [Flot Pie Examples](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/pie.html)

just go to the lower example (Donut) , place the mouse over the lower or the upper slice and leave quickly with the mouse , notice that the slice is still highlighted

I can tell when the mouse leaves the chart container (using the mouseleave event) but how can i get rid of the highlight ?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, sadly the pie plugin does not expose any methods that let you unhighlight.  In general, if the plugin was written more sanely, you could call `plot.unhighlight()` on mouseleave of your placeholder div... But this is not a perfect world, so instead you have to do something nasty like this:

```
$("#interactive").mouseleave(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event('mousemove');
    e.pageX = 1;
    e.pageY = 1;
    $('#interactive canvas:first').trigger(e);
});​
```

You set pageX and pageY to be something you are sure will never be part of the pie and then this generates a move event in that spot, which tricks the pie into unhighlighting itself.  If you also have the click events setup, you might need to also generate a click event in the same spot (just change `mousemove` to `click`.

See it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/9LdKg/